# Powershell - Set DHCP scope option to a predefined value

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I am looking for a way to set DHCP Scope options on a scope so that when the predefined default value for the server is changed, it changes on the scope.

When I use the MMC Snap In to turn an option on(and it has a predefined option value), this is how it works, so I know it's possible, i just don't know if it's possible WITH POWERSHELL.

Anyone know if there is a way, directly or indirectly, to achieve this in powershell?

To clarify, If I check a box on the MMC Snap In for Scope Option 042, it will set the value to, lets say "1.2.3.4", automatically. If i go change that value on the server's predefined option list, it also changes on the scope. 
If I use set-dhcpserverv4optionvalue to set that same option to "1.2.3.4", then change the predefined option, the scope stays at "1.2.3.4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clarification is a little bit ambiguous, but my interpretation is that you are:

1. Enabling a *scope level* option with a pre-defined value (inherited from the *server level*).
2. Changing the *server level* pre-defined value, which then changes the value at the *scope level*.
3. Changing the *scope level* value using `Set-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ScopeId`.
4. Changing the *server level* pre-defined value, which then does **not** change the *scope level* value.

If my interpretation is correct, then this is the expected behavior. You might thing about this like you would Cascading Style Sheets or Group Policy Objects: the most specific setting wins.

Once you set the *value* at the scope level, it no longer inherits its value from the server level.

If you use `Set-DchpServerv4OptionValue` without specifying `-ScopeId` then it will set the *server level* value.

### Edit based on comment:

Now that I better understand, I think that this functionality is missing in the PowerShell cmdlets. You could set the server level default value, and you can set an explicit value on a scope, but I don't see any way of enabling an option on a scope that uses the default value rather than an explicit one.

The DHCP cmdlets are fairly thin wrappers around the underlying CIM/WMI objects, so it might be possible with CIM/WMI calls, but I don't know how to do it offhand.

Comment: The issue isn't that the behavior is unexpected, but rather that it is inconvenient, and I want to find a workaround. What i want to do is number 1 of your list, but with powershell, so i don't have to do 3. Is there a way to enable the scope level option and make the scope level option inherit the server level value through powershell?